# How to solve equation containing exponential in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, calculus

I am trying to solve an equation using **Solve** and **linsolve** method. Other equations have worked before with these function but I think for equation with exponential term has some other function and I can't seem to find it .Here is my Equation

```
P= -0.45 - 100.0*exp(-0.125*t)/(1 + 4*exp(-t/32)) + 100.0*exp(-0.15625*t)/(1 + 4*exp(-t/32))**2
```

I used **solve** and **linsolve** but it did work and gave me **[]** and **empty set** as an output respectively. I tried the same equation in maple and it works the answer is 49.24 and so I can say that there is nothing wrong with the equation. But i want to do this in python. Thanks

Comment: How do you know you coded the function correctly?  Can you post that?

Answer (score 2):

**Solve** and **linsolve** deals with linear equations while you have non-linear.
For you equation you need to use non-lenear solvers. For example SciPy methods:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html